# python: write data in .csv file disorder

Tags: python

```
#write data in .csv file
def data_save_csv(type,data,id,name,header,since = None):
    #get the date when storage data
    date_storage()
    #create the data storage directory
    csv_parent_directory = os.path.join("dataset","csv",type,glovar.date)

    #write data in .csv
    if type == "group_members":
        csv_file_prefix = "gm"
    elif type == "group_feed":
        csv_file_prefix = "gf"
    elif type == "public_figure_posts":
        csv_file_prefix = "pfp"
    elif "user_" in type:
        # create the data storage directory
        csv_parent_directory = os.path.join("dataset", "csv", "user", type, glovar.date)
        if type == "user_friends":
            csv_file_prefix = "uf"
        elif type == "user_likes":
            csv_file_prefix = "ul"
        elif type == "user_feed":
            csv_file_prefix = "uf"
    # create (mkdir) the csv_parent_directory
    directory_create(csv_parent_directory)

    if since:
        csv_file_name = csv_file_prefix + "_" + since.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + "_" + time_storage() + id + "_" +name + ".csv"
    else:
        csv_file_name = csv_file_prefix + "_"  + time_storage() + "_" + id + "_" +name + ".csv"
     csv_file_directory = os.path.join(csv_parent_directory,csv_file_name)

    if type == "user_feed":
        feed = data
        for item in feed:
            # parse the feed data from group_download.py
            print("id=" + item['id'] + ",")
            print("permalink_url=" + item['permalink_url'] + ",")
            print("created_time=" + item['created_time'] + ",")
            print("updated_time=" + item['updated_time'] + ",")
            print("name=" + item['from']['name'] + ",")
            print("from_id=" + item['from']['id'] + ",")
            print("message=" + item['message'] + ",")
            print("link=" + item['link'] + ",")
            print("likes_total_count=" + str(item['likes']['summary']['total_count']) + ",")
            print("comments_total_count=" + str(item['comments']['summary']['total_count']) + ",")

    with open(csv_file_directory,'w',newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:

        writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        #csv header
        writer.writerow(header)

        #if data is group members(group_manage.py)
        if type == "group_members" or "user_friends" or "user_likes":
            row = []
            for i in range(len(data)):
                for k in data[i].keys():
                    if isinstance(data[i][k],bool):
                        data[i][k] = str(data[i][k])
                    row.append(data[i][k])

            writer.writerow(row)
            row = []
        #if data is group feed(group_download.py)
        elif type == "group_feed" or "public_figure_posts" or "user_feed":
            feed = data
            for item in feed:
                #parse the feed data from group_download.py
                row = [item['id'],item['permalink_url'],item['created_time'],item['updated_time'],item['from']['name'],item['from']['id'],item['message'],item['link'],item['likes']['summary']['total_count'],item['comments']['summary']['total_count']]
                writer.writerow(row)

    csvfile.close()
```

Write a python program to write data in .csv file, when the type is “user_feed”,
I print the items of the data:

```
id=110286969468305_112459422584393,
permalink_url=https://www.facebook.com/110286969468305/posts/112459422584393,
created_time=2016-12-18T12:44:52+0000,
updated_time=2016-12-18T12:47:10+0000,
name=Dewi Nurfitri Oktaviani,
from_id=10202749157833181,
message=Hi, nice to meet you,
link=,
likes_total_count=0,
comments_total_count=1,
```

They are right, but when write the data in the .csv file, I found the sequence of the data does not match the head order, the head is :

```
header = ["POST ID", "Permalink", "Create time", "Updated time", "Author", "Author ID", "Message", "Link", "Likes", "Comments"]
```

and you can see that in this method "data_save_csv",

```
elif type == "group_feed" or "public_figure_posts" or "user_feed":
    feed = data
    for item in feed:
         #parse the feed data from group_download.py
         row = [item['id'],item['permalink_url'],item['created_time'],item['updated_time'],item['from']['name'],item['from']['id'],item['message'],item['link'],item['likes']['summary']['total_count'],item['comments']['summary']['total_count']]
         writer.writerow(row)
```

You can see that the sequence of the data item is the same with that in the     head, but when I open the csv file, I found the sequence of the head item is    right, but the sequence of the data item is disorder, no "id" data, and the other items order is not in the right order.

could you please help me?

[image: Data Structure]

Comment: Does every item has a value?

Comment: added embedded image

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: This line

`if type == "group_members" or "user_friends" or "user_likes":`

isn't doing what you want. The expression always evaluates to `True`. Possible replacements:

`if type == "group_members" or type == "user_friends" or type == "user_likes":`

`if type in ("group_members", "user_friends", "user_likes", ):`

`if type in {"group_members", "user_friends", "user_likes", }:`

and this line

```
elif type == "group_feed" or "public_figure_posts" or "user_feed":
```

has the same problem. You should fix both lines and try again.

Comment: I modify the program to   if type == "group_members" or type == "user_friends" or type == "user_likes":, but it still error, the items in .csv file is still disorder

Comment: now fix the line that starts with `elif type` (as per my answer) and try again